# Can get the enemy to chase me and hit me but when he hits me he disappears to the other side of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I setup a debug log to see if something is not getting called. All the logs show up in console. The enemy can hit the player but when he does so it shows up on the other side of the player.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0McNnxUVM4o&feature=youtu.be is a video of what's going on.

I'm trying to get the enemy to run up to the player, stop, hit the player and stay on one side of the player instead of going to the other side. The only other script I have tied to the enemy is an HP one. Would it be better to set it on `OnTriggerEvent`?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed;
    public GameObject Target;
    public float lookRadius = 10f;
    // Attack
    public int AttackDamageMin;
    public int AttackDamageMax;
    public float AttackCooldownTimeMain;
    public float AttackCooldownTime;
    public float minAttackDistance = 10f;

    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start()
    {
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);
        Debug.Log("Float Dist");

        if(distance < minAttackDistance)
        {
            StopEnemy();
            Debug.Log("Enemy Stop");

            AttackTarget();
            Debug.Log("Player is Attacked");
            agent.SetDestination(target.position);

            if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
            {
                Facetarget();
                Debug.Log("Enemy is now Facing Player");
            }
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movementSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
            GoToTarget();
            Debug.Log("Enemy is now going to Player");

            if (AttackCooldownTime > 0)
            {
                AttackCooldownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                Debug.Log("Attack is now on Cooldown");
            }
            else
            {
                AttackCooldownTime = AttackCooldownTimeMain;
            }
        }
    }

    void AttackTarget()
    {
        Target.transform.GetComponent<Player>().TakeDamage(Random.Range(AttackDamageMin, AttackDamageMax));
        Debug.Log("Attacking");
    }

    void GoToTarget()
    {
        agent.isStopped = false;
        agent.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("Gototarget");
    }

    void StopEnemy()
    {
        agent.isStopped = true;
        Debug.Log("Stop");
    }

    void Facetarget()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, lookRadius);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line here

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movementSpeed);
```

Seems to be the problem, you are moving your enemy forward a significant amount. This is happening every frame and is not scaled by delta time.
I'm not sure if you mean to be moving your enemy forward here but if you are you should scale it by delta time

```
 transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, first time coding, but that seems to work, but now I need to fix the attack delay. Now when the enemy gets to the player it consistency attacks, instead of attack and wait for cool-down then attack again, but I think I see which code line I need to change.

Comment: Stack overflow is really designed for each question to only be asking one question, that way other people with similar problems can find your question and see what answer worked for you. It's more than OK to make a new question though. If you pick an answer for this question and then write out your new problem in a new question, link that in a comment here and i'll take a look